# PhpStorm & Firefox debugging issue

Tags: php, debugging, firefox, phpstorm, xdebug

I have successfully configured Xdebug to PhpStorm, however, the Xdebug helper isn't communicating with the PhpStorm and I cannot figure out why. Others have a somewhat similar issue in regards to Xdebug not workings, but it isnt the fix I am looking for.

I am trying to query an url in the browser and trip the breakpoint, but it doesn't work. If I chose `debug` within PhpStorm it will trip the breakpoint. I tried Chrome and Firefox no luck. I'm on a Fedora 28 workstation.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm in case if you have not seen it yet.

Comment: *"...however, the Xdebug helper isn't communicating with the PhpStorm..."* Xdebug helper just sets the Xdebug cookie -- nothing more. The rest is about configuring Xdebug & PhpStorm itself. I suggest https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm since you already trying to use browser extension.

Comment: By chance, did you turn on debugging?

Comment: @RobertoMaldonado start php debug connection?